# How to correctly extract a string from a user space pointer in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I wrote a hook for the `execve` system call and in the beginning when I wrote it to print `"hi"`, each time that a file is executed. It worked fine, but when I tried to print the `filename` that is passed to the system call this resulted in a crash and of course I had to restart my computer.

This is my code:

```
static asmlinkage long our_execl(const char __user * filename,
            const char __user * const __user * argv,
            const char __user * const __user * envp) {
    printk("%s\n",filename);
    return original_execl(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

This is how I inject the new syscall:

```
static int lkm_example_init(void)
{

    printk("new new new 2");

    write_cr0(read_cr0()&(~ 0x10000));

    sys_call_table = (void*)0xdd8c4240//the syscall address from the   /proc/kallsyms ;

    execl= sys_call_table[__NR_execve];
    sys_call_table[__NR_execve]=our_execl;

    write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0X10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh boy! Seems like everyone's trying to hack into some syscall there days ... Anyway, you're not showing how you're hooking up your own execl handler. I'd say that's quite relevant to the issue ...

Comment: I believe that "everyone's trying to hack into some syscall" because this is an interesting (for education) task, and probably it is the default task in some educational course. Unfortunately, there are lots of old materials which explain how to hijack Linux syscalls with old kernels and I've already saw few similar questions, arising due to the fact that the OP used new kernels, which require different approach in the hijacking.

Comment: I can send the way i hooked it if you went but like i said before the hook is working fine @dragosht

Comment: I agree with @dragosht - we need the exact code of syscall hijacking and the kernel version too.

Comment: Looks like you failed to call `copy_from_user()` here.

Comment: i cant see why you dislike my question and why should i copy the char pointer to kernel space is it pointer to user space address

Comment: @DanielHaish You have to copy the _whole filename_ to kernel space and print that copied buffer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is most likely happening here is that SMAP ([Supervisor Mode Access Prevention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisor_Mode_Access_Prevention)) is preventing the kernel from accessing a raw user space pointer, causing a panic.

The correct way to access a string from user space is to copy its content using [`strncpy_from_user()`](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re252.html) first. Also, be careful and make sure to correctly terminate the string.

```
static asmlinkage long our_execl(const char __user * filename,
            const char __user * const __user * argv,
            const char __user * const __user * envp) {
    char buf[256];
    buf[255] = '\0';

    long res = strncpy_from_user(buf, filename, 255);
    if (res > 0)
        printk("%s\n", buf);

    return original_execl(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

In this case, since we are specifically talking about a file name, depending on the kernel version you may be able to use the [`getname()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/fs/namei.c#L217) and [`putname()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/fs/namei.c#L259) from [`linux/fs.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/include/linux/fs.h) (if they are exported in the kernel version you are working with). These work using a [`struct filename`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2517).

```
static asmlinkage long our_execl(const char __user * filename,
            const char __user * const __user * argv,
            const char __user * const __user * envp) {

    struct filename *fname = getname(filename);
    if (!IS_ERR(fname)) {
        printk("%s\n", fname->name);
        putname(fname);
    }

    return original_execl(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

Comment: of course i changed the buffer just to  char * instead of char*[]

Comment: @Daniel, I hope you meant `char[]` there, rather than an uninitialised `char*`.

Comment: @Toby Speight   I thought it will be batter to copy it to a pointer so i used pointer and malloc

Comment: @DanielHaish using `kmalloc` is usually discouraged in kernel code. If the buffer is small enough or doesn't need dynamic allocation you should avoid it.

Comment: getname/putname cannot be used from modules anymore https://lkml.kernel.org/linux-fsdevel/1349137018-21948-21-git-send-email-jlayton@redhat.com/

Comment: @JacekTomaka thanks, yet another kernel symbol out of reach :')

Answer (score 3):

Just in addition to Marco's answer.
If something goes wrong you can always look at how this is already implemented. Fortunately, the sources are open and anyone can access it.

Specifically, here you want to use some "string" (pointer to char) in syscall handler which arrives from user-mode. So you can take a look at how are such strings handled in real syscalls. E.g. [`do_execve()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/fs/exec.c#L1758) for `execve` syscall:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(execve,
        const char __user *, filename,
        const char __user *const __user *, argv,
        const char __user *const __user *, envp)
{
    return do_execve(getname(filename), argv, envp);
}
```

takes `filename` returned from [`getname()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/fs/namei.c#L125) function, which eventually invokes `strncpy_from_user()`:

```
struct filename *
getname_flags(const char __user *filename, int flags, int *empty)
{

    //...
    len = strncpy_from_user(kname, filename, EMBEDDED_NAME_MAX);
    if (unlikely(len < 0)) {
        __putname(result);
        return ERR_PTR(len);
    }
    //...
```